# Неявное приведение типов

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Есть 2 класса:

```
class A
{
    public:
      A(int a_=0):x(a_) {}
      A operator + (A const &x_) const
      {
         return A(x+x_.x);
      }
      operator double() const
      {
         return (double) x;
      }
    private:
      int x;
};
class B
{
    public:
      B(double b_=0):y(b_) {}
      B operator + (B const &y_) const
      {
         return B(y+y_.y);
      }
      operator int() const
      {
         return (int) y;
      }
    private:
      double y;
};
```

Какова будет последовательность действий компилятора в следующих случаях:

```
A res_a(5);B res_b(10.5);
A res_ab = res_a + res_b ; // <------
A res_ba = res_b + res_a ; // <------
B res_ab = res_a + res_b ; // <------
B res_ba = res_b + res_a ; // <------
```

Comment: debug не пробовали?

Comment: @Saidolim не употребляю

Comment: @free_bsd тогда есть смысл развивать свои экстрасенсорные способности

Comment: У g++ есть ключ `-S` для вывода ассемблерного кода, в других компиляторах тоже должна быть такакя фича.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть изменяем конструкторы:

```
B(double b_=0):y(b_) { cout << "B const" << y << endl; }
A(int a_=0):x(a_) { cout << "A const" <<x << endl; }
```

, запускаем, и все становится ясно:

```
A res_ab = res_a + res_b ; // res_a->double, res_b->int, double->int, A(int)
A res_ba = res_b + res_a ; // то же самое
B res_ab = res_a + res_b ; // res_a->double, res_b->int, B(double)
B res_ba = res_b + res_a ; // same
```

Чтобы проверить, можно вывод в операторы приведения типов вставить. В принципе, это и так можно понять, т.к. приведения между А и В нет, также, как и А+В.